# Getting exception and I don't know why

Tags: java, runtime-error

```
import java.util.Scanner;               //Import necessary classes 
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;



public class Lab11
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

        final int LIMIT = 1000, MAX = 10, MIN = -10;        //number of ints to be read into file
        String fileName;            //holds name of file


        System.out.print("Enter the name of the file to hold the integers: ");
        fileName = scan.next();
        PrintWriter outFile = null;         //creates PrintWriter to write to specified file

        try
        {
            outFile = new PrintWriter(new File(fileName));      //TryCatch statement to catch any errors when file opens
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File "+fileName+" doesn't exist.  Exiting program");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= LIMIT; i++) {        //for loop to write to file using random num between -10 and 10
            outFile.print((int)(Math.random()*(MAX+1-MIN)) + MIN + " ");        //makes sure numbers in file are separated by spaces
            outFile.close();        //closes file for output
        }


        Scanner inFile = null;      //creates scanner to read in file
        try     //TryCatch statement to catch errors
        {
            inFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));       
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File "+fileName+" doesn't exist.  Exiting program");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        int num, neg = 0, pos = 0, zero = 0;        //variables to hold current number, positives, negatives and average
        double avg = 0;

        while (inFile.hasNext())        // Use a while loop to read in numbers from the file until the end
        {       
            inFile.nextLine();
            fileName = inFile.nextLine();
            avg = 0;
            num = 0;

            while(inFile.hasNextInt())
            {
                num = inFile.nextInt();
                avg += num;         //adds current num to avg

                if (num > 0)
                    pos++;      //checks if positive and adds one to total pos
                if (num < 0)
                    neg++;      //checks is negative and adds one to total neg
                else
                    zero++;     //checks for zeros and adds one to total
            }
            avg = (avg/LIMIT);      //calculates actual average
            inFile.close();     //closes file for input
        }

        outFile = null;         //Opens file for output again

        try
        {
            outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true));      //TryCatch statement to catch any errors when file opens
        }                                                                       //Allows file to be appended to instead of truncated
        catch (IOException e)       
        {
            System.out.println("File "+fileName+" doesn't exist.  Exiting program");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

            System.out.println("\n\nNumber of negative numbers in the file: " + neg);
            System.out.println("\nNumber of positive numbers in the file: " + pos);
            System.out.println("\nNumber of zeroes in the file: " + zero);
            System.out.println("\nAverage of the numbers in the file: " + fmt.format(avg));

            outFile.print("Number of negative numbers in the file: " + neg);
            outFile.print("Number of positive numbers in the file: " + pos);
            outFile.print("Number of zeroes in the file: " + zero);
            outFile.print("Average of the numbers in the file: " + fmt.format(avg));

            outFile.close();
}  // End of main
}
```

I'm taking intro to Java and I am just brutal at it.  No matter how many hours I practice or study I just don't get it. I got this much done but now I'm getting this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
  at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
  at Lab11.main(Lab11.java:89)
```

I have no idea where I went wrong.  Any guidance would be great. Thanks.

Comment: *"I have no idea where I went wrong"*  Start with `Lab11.main(Lab11.java:89)`..

Comment: codin needs some patience ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus on : `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found`

Look at this piece of code.

```
 while (inFile.hasNext())        // Use a while loop to read in numbers from the file until the end
    {       
        inFile.nextLine();
        fileName = inFile.nextLine();
```

Say your file has only one line. Then, `inFile.nextLine();` has already read it. After which there NO more lines. So, remove `inFile.nextLine()`.

Your code should now be:

```
 while (inFile.hasNext())        // Use a while loop to read in numbers from the file until the end
    {       
        fileName = inFile.nextLine();
```

Also, as syb0rg mentioned please refrain from using too many next functions at once. You'd only confuse yourself.

Comment: Thank you that helped some but now it's just moved the problem up to Line 86 so I'm assuming my whole while loop is screwy. Thing is, as far as I can tell I'm following all my class notes and book perfectly. So frustrating. You guys are helpful though. I appreciate it.

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us what the file contains and what you want to do with it?

Comment: Duh, sorry, first time. It is supposed to just contain 1000 random ints and be accessed by user entering lab11.txt.  Then count all the pos, neg and zeros and calculate the average.

Comment: Also the exception has changed and it says "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed"

Comment: So aside from a couple organizational issues the real problem was that I had 1 too many while loops in there.  To all those that replied, I appreciate your time. Thanks again.